# Jquery file upload plugin how to fetch Response sent from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

i am using jquery file upload plugin provided at https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
now the problem is that i am returning image paths for the matching images that i just uploaded if following format.

```
["upload\/2014-04-08-17-04-39000000_d.jpg","upload\/2014-04-08-17-04-39000000_d.jpg","upload\/2014-04-08-17-04-39000000_d.jpg","upload\/2014-04-08-17-04-39000000_d.jpg","upload\/2014-04-08-17-04-39000000_d.jpg","upload\/2014-04-08-17-04-39000000_d.jpg","upload\/2014-04-08-17-04-39000000_d.jpg"]
```

now i cant figure out that how can i fetch this reponse. I mean usually ajax response can be fetched within `success` function but i cant figure out where is similar function in the following uploader.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In fileupload.js there is a call back function done.
Use this code.

```
done: function(e, data) {
                var r = data.result;
                alert(r);
            },
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try binding: `.bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})` ?

That should be the callback you are looking for.